# Create html drop down based on existing menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this menu:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="index" href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Other</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>                               
        </li>
        <li><a class="news" href="#">News</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I need to generate a drop-down(select) list using jQuery on page load.

So far I have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {        

        //build dropdown
        $("<select />").appendTo("nav");

        // Create default option "Go to..."
            $("<option />", {
            "selected": "selected",
            "value"   : "",
            "text"    : "Go to..."
            }).appendTo("nav select");  

            // Populate dropdowns with the first menu items
            $("nav li a").each(function() {
                var el = $(this);
                $("<option />", {
                    "value"   : el.attr("href"),
                    "text"    : el.text()
                }).appendTo("nav select");
            });

            //make responsive dropdown menu actually work           
            $("nav select").change(function() {
                window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            });

});
</script>
```

This jQuery code does the job taking into account sub-menu items, but generated list does not indent submenu items in drop-down list.

What I'd like to have is a " - " infront of drop-down list items (if they are actually original menu sub-menu items), so they could be easily identified.

Hope this makes sense.

Please advice,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work for a menu of any depth / complexity:

### [See this working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/MfBKd/1/)

```
// Populate dropdowns with the first menu items
$("nav ul li a").each(function () {
    var el = $(this),
        depth = el.parents("ul").length - 1,
        indent = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        indent = indent + " - ";
    }
    $("<option />", {
        "value": el.attr("href"),
        "text" : indent + el.text()
    }).appendTo("nav select");
});
```

This calculates a "depth" based on how many parent `<ul>` elements each link has, and then indents its `<option>` text accordingly. This script will work with as deep of a menu, and with as many submenu items, as you need, without further manipulation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/tXdBa/1/

this method works by adding a "nested" class to nested ul tags.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    //build dropdown
    $("<select />").appendTo("nav");

    // Create default option "Go to..."
        $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value"   : "",
        "text"    : "Go to..."
        }).appendTo("nav select");  

        // Populate dropdowns with the first menu items
        $("nav li a").each(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            if(!el.closest('.nested').length > 0){
                intend='';                
            }else{
                intend='---';
            }
            $("<option />", {
                "value"   : el.attr("href"),
                "text"    : intend+el.text()
            }).appendTo("nav select");
        });

        //make responsive dropdown menu actually work           
        $("nav select").change(function() {
            window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        });

});
```